# SSRS - forcing the domain log in prompt for some reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have some SSRS reports set up based on Windows integrated security (RSWindowsNegotiate & RSWindowsNTLM).

Is there a way to force the SSRS to prompt login credentials for some of the reports (not all) for added security? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Go to your Data Source Properties window as above, then Credentials and then select "Prompt for credntials" instead of Use Windows Authentication (integrated security)